# Rails not picking up strings from form hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

In my application I have a form that contains two date fields hooked up to date objects on the model. For some reason, whether they save to the DB or not is a crapshoot - sometimes they do, sometimes they don't, resulting in entries with blank date fields.

This is particularly strange because the sent hash contains properly formatted date strings, but Rails just ignores them. When I try to perform an action on them in the controller (converting the strings to date objects, for instance) it acts as if they're nil even though I can see them sitting right there in the hash.

What could I be doing wrong? I'm sure it's something absurdly simple but I just can't see it.

Comment: listing some code can help.

Comment: There's not much to list. It's a standard textfield and I'm not manipulating anything in while saving. `<%= f.text_field :arrived_at, id:"dp1" %>`

Comment: You probably have some associated controller code as well. You mentioned that the controller acts as if the date strings are nil, even though you can "see" them in the hash. What do you mean by "see" in this context?